# Stack Overflow Careers Profile Empty

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I had a Stack Overflow Career profile that was complete and had every section filled in.

It used the same credentials as this Stack Overflow account to access.

Today, I got a message from a recruiter and after login I've found that everything has disappeared, even my name.

[image]

What is going on? Or am I being really dumb?

Edit:

Another symptom is that that on Stack Overflow, I see the notification, but when I select it, it takes me to Careers and 'Not Found'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't panic, your Careers profile is still there. :-)

It looks like your original Careers user account is associated with your Facebook credentials, so please log out of Careers and log back in again using Facebook and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this!